# Elements in div overlapping on resize Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm having issue with my labels overlapping within my div row

My bootstrap looks as follows

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-2 ">
          <div class='card'>
               <div class='card-block'
                 <div class="row text-nowrap">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6" for="FinalMonthEnd">Final Month End:</label>
                    <kendo-dropdownlist class="col-xs-11 col-md-11 col-lg-5" id="FinalMonthEnd">
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>
                  </div>
            </div>
         </div>  
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10 ">
         <kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]='grid' >       
         </kendo-grid>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I had to add this to my css as the label text is large so when it gets resized the text will go to the next line one letter at a time.

```
.text-nowrap {
   white-space: nowrap;      
}
```

When the page is resized down before it gets to the col-md threshold the two start merging together and overlapping each other and looks terrible. How can I prevent this so that each stay separate?

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using? and can you share the complete code of the `form`?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 I''ve updated the code

Comment: (1) `<div class='card-block'` is missing a `>`.

(2) Try applying `form-group` class instead of `row` to parent div of `label` and `kendo-dropdownlist`.

(3) Try adding `form-control` class to `kendo-dropdownlist`.

(4) Class prefix `col-xs` is dropped in Bootstrap v4.0 and is no more recognizable. You should use `col-` instead (although it will not make difference to your code, just mentioned it for info).  Hope this can help with some direction.

Comment: Can you comment this as an answer please?

Comment: Why that? I can't test with kendo-dropdownlist right now. Rest of what I suggested is working fine in testing at my end.

Comment: Yes if you make it an answer instead of a comment I can accept it and you get your credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) `<div class='card-block'` is missing a `>`.

(2) Try applying `form-group` class instead of `row` to parent div of `label` and `kendo-dropdownlist`.

(3) Try adding `form-control` class to `kendo-dropdownlist`.

(4) Class prefix `col-xs` is dropped in Bootstrap v4.0 and is no more recognizable. You should use `col-` instead (although it will not make difference to your code, just mentioned it for info).

Hope this can help with some direction.